# Append rows to groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append a number of NaN rows to each group in a pandas dataframe. Essentially I want to pad each group to be 5 rows long. Ordering is important. I have:

```
    Rank id
0   1  a
1   2  a
2   3  a
3   4  a
4   5  a
5   1  c
6   2  c
7   1  e
8   2  e
9   3  e
```

I want:

```
    Rank id
0   1    a
1   2    a
2   3    a
3   4    a
4   5    a
5   1    c
6   2    c
7   NaN  c
8   NaN  c
9   NaN  c
10  1    e
11  2    e
12  3    e
13  NaN  e
14  NaN  e
```

Comment: it's losing the index 5 in your dataframe. You said that the groups should be 5 rows long, but they're not like this in your demonstration. Why?

Comment: This was a copy/paste mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pd.crosstab`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.Rank, df.ID).iloc[:5].unstack().reset_index()
df.loc[(df[0]==0),'Rank'] = np.nan
del df[0]
```

Output:

```
   ID  Rank
0   a   1.0
1   a   2.0
2   a   3.0
3   a   4.0
4   a   5.0
5   c   1.0
6   c   2.0
7   c   NaN
8   c   NaN
9   c   NaN
10  e   1.0
11  e   2.0
12  e   3.0
13  e   NaN
14  e   NaN
```

Another approach, assuming the maximum group size in `df` is exactly 5.

```
In [251]: df.groupby('ID').Rank.apply(np.array).apply(pd.Series).stack(dropna=False)
Out[251]: 
ID
a   0    1.0
    1    2.0
    2    3.0
    3    4.0
    4    5.0
c   0    1.0
    1    2.0
    2    NaN
    3    NaN
    4    NaN
e   0    1.0
    1    2.0
    2    3.0
    3    NaN
    4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Full explanation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO("""Rank ID
0   1  a
1   2  a
2   3  a
3   4  a
4   5  a
6   1  c
7   2  c
8   1  e
9   2  e
10  3  e"""), sep=r' +')

df = pd.crosstab(df.Rank, df.ID).iloc[:5].T.stack().reset_index()
df.loc[(df[0]==0),'Rank'] = np.nan
del df[0]

# pd.crosstab(df.Rank, df.ID) produces:

# ID    a  c  e
# Rank
# 1.0   1  1  1
# 2.0   1  1  1
# 3.0   1  0  1
# 4.0   1  0  0
# 5.0   1  0  0

# applying .T.stack().reset_index() yields:

   # ID  Rank  0
# 0   a   1.0  1
# 1   a   2.0  1
# 2   a   3.0  1
# 3   a   4.0  1
# 4   a   5.0  1
# 5   c   1.0  1
# 6   c   2.0  1
# 7   c   3.0  0
# 8   c   4.0  0
# 9   c   5.0  0
# 10  e   1.0  1
# 11  e   2.0  1
# 12  e   3.0  1
# 13  e   4.0  0
# 14  e   5.0  0

# finally, use df[0] to filter df['Rank']
```

Comment: Really nice approach perhaps replace your second line with `df.loc[(df[0]==0),'Rank']=np.nan`

Answer (score 4):

### `concat` and `reindex`

This solution does not consider the values in the `Rank` column and only adds more rows if more are needed.

```
pd.concat([
    d.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(5)).assign(id=n)
    for n, d in df.groupby('id')
], ignore_index=True)

    Rank id
0    1.0  a
1    2.0  a
2    3.0  a
3    4.0  a
4    5.0  a
5    1.0  c
6    2.0  c
7    NaN  c
8    NaN  c
9    NaN  c
10   1.0  e
11   2.0  e
12   3.0  e
13   NaN  e
14   NaN  e
```

---

Same answer phrased a bit differently

```
f = lambda t: t[1].reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(5)).assign(id=t[0])
pd.concat(map(f, df.groupby('id')), ignore_index=True)
```

---

### `factorize`

This solution produces the Cartesian product of unique values from `id` and `Rank`

```
i, r = df.id.factorize()
j, c = df.Rank.factorize()
b = np.empty((r.size, c.size))
b.fill(np.nan)
b[i, j] = df.Rank.values

pd.DataFrame(dict(Rank=b.ravel(), id=r.repeat(c.size)))

    Rank id
0    1.0  a
1    2.0  a
2    3.0  a
3    4.0  a
4    5.0  a
5    1.0  c
6    2.0  c
7    NaN  c
8    NaN  c
9    NaN  c
10   1.0  e
11   2.0  e
12   3.0  e
13   NaN  e
14   NaN  e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the frequency of the id's and `pd.concat` to merge the repetitions i.e

```
di = (5-df.groupby('id').size()).to_dict()

temp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({
                'Rank':np.nan,
                'id': pd.Series(np.repeat(i,di[i]))
                }) for i in df['id'].unique()])

ndf = pd.concat([df,temp],ignore_index=True).sort_values('id')

    Rank id
0    1.0  a
1    2.0  a
2    3.0  a
3    4.0  a
4    5.0  a
5    1.0  c
6    2.0  c
10   NaN  c
11   NaN  c
12   NaN  c
7    1.0  e
8    2.0  e
9    3.0  e
13   NaN  e
14   NaN  e
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is create helper `DataFrame` by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and then `append` to original, last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
s = (5 - df['id'].value_counts())
df = (df.append(pd.DataFrame({'id':np.repeat(s.index, s.values), 'Rank':np.nan}))
       .sort_values('id')
       .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
    Rank id
0    1.0  a
1    2.0  a
2    3.0  a
3    4.0  a
4    5.0  a
5    1.0  c
6    2.0  c
7    NaN  c
8    NaN  c
9    NaN  c
10   1.0  e
11   2.0  e
12   3.0  e
13   NaN  e
14   NaN  e
```

Another solution is no sorting is possible is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function and `append`:

```
def f(x):
    return x.append(pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, x.name]] * (5 - len(x)), columns=['Rank','id']))
df = df.groupby('id', sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Rank id
0     1  a
1     2  a
2     3  a
3     4  a
4     5  a
5     1  c
6     2  c
7   NaN  c
8   NaN  c
9   NaN  c
10    1  e
11    2  e
12    3  e
13  NaN  e
14  NaN  e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a single `pd.DataFrame.append` following by `sort_values`.

```
from itertools import chain

counts = df.groupby('id')['Rank'].count()

lst = list(chain.from_iterable([[np.nan, i]]*(5-c) for i, c in counts.items()))

res = df.append(pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=df.columns))\
        .sort_values(['id', 'Rank'])\
        .reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

    Rank id
0    1.0  a
1    2.0  a
2    3.0  a
3    4.0  a
4    5.0  a
5    1.0  c
6    2.0  c
7    NaN  c
8    NaN  c
9    NaN  c
10   1.0  e
11   2.0  e
12   3.0  e
13   NaN  e
14   NaN  e
```

Answer (score 0):

excellent answers so far. i had another idea because it fits more to the problem i'm dealing with, using an **outer join** and `pd.merge`.
in addition to the example from above, i have several metric columns (m1 and m2 in this example) that i want to set to zero for every group that does not contain those Rank values. in my case, Rank is simply a time dimension, and i the df contains a time series over several IDs.

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO("""Rank ID m1 m2
0   1  a 1 3
1   2  a 2 3
2   3  a 1 2
3   4  a 1 3
4   5  a 2 3
6   1  c 2 2
7   2  c 2 4
8   1  e 1 3
9   2  e 1 4
10  3  e 1 2"""), sep=r' +')
```

i then define the df that contains all the Ranks, in this example from 1 to 10.

```
df_outer_right = pd.DataFrame({'Rank':np.arange(1,11,1)})
```

finally, i group the initial df by ID and apply an outer join using pd.merge on each group.

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda df: pd.merge(df, df_outer_right, how='outer', on='Rank'))
```

which yields:

```
ID  Rank    ID  m1  m2
a   0   1   a   1.0 3.0
a   1   2   a   2.0 3.0
a   2   3   a   1.0 2.0
a   3   4   a   1.0 3.0
a   4   5   a   2.0 3.0
a   5   6   NaN NaN NaN
a   6   7   NaN NaN NaN
a   7   8   NaN NaN NaN
a   8   9   NaN NaN NaN
a   9   10  NaN NaN NaN
c   0   1   c   2.0 2.0
c   1   2   c   2.0 4.0
c   2   3   NaN NaN NaN
c   3   4   NaN NaN NaN
c   4   5   NaN NaN NaN
c   5   6   NaN NaN NaN
c   6   7   NaN NaN NaN
c   7   8   NaN NaN NaN
c   8   9   NaN NaN NaN
c   9   10  NaN NaN NaN
e   0   1   e   1.0 3.0
e   1   2   e   1.0 4.0
e   2   3   e   1.0 2.0
e   3   4   NaN NaN NaN
e   4   5   NaN NaN NaN
e   5   6   NaN NaN NaN
e   6   7   NaN NaN NaN
e   7   8   NaN NaN NaN
e   8   9   NaN NaN NaN
e   9   10  NaN NaN NaN
```

i'm pretty sure this might not be the fastest solution :)